# Button for a modal form not displaying or functioning

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've already been on here for a similar question, but moved this interaction in my code and have the same issue... but I believe with a different cause.

I have a page that has an "Email Me" button at the bottom of it:
http://danux.me/

When you click the "Email Me" button, an overlay should appear and with an email form in the middle of it. I had it working on a test page, and then moved all the items over to my index.html and it's not working.

My goal right now is just to get the overlay and form to pop up in the page.

I checked my paths to make sure they were right and I think they are, but I don't know how to parse or inspect php with Google's emulator to see where something might not be working.

I checked my index.html head link to the css, the javascript at the end of my index.html and then in the contact.js, there's a GET link that points down to the php file.

Also, I am unsure in the HTML how to "call"(?) the php or jquery on that button and if that's the issue. It worked before as is and I am assuming that class="contact" is what's making all this work? I don't know. I'd be interested to know how a class triggers a javascript file.

I also got ripped earlier for not having PHP, but I didn't know until today that can't be viewed, so I'll put it below. I'm not sure if it's helpful or not.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
 var contact = {
    message: null,
    init: function () {
        $('#contact-form input.contact, #contact-form a.contact').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // load the contact form using ajax
            $.get("contact/data/contact.php", function(data){
                // create a modal dialog with the data
                $(data).modal({
                    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                    position: ["15%",],
                    overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                    containerId: 'contact-container',
                    onOpen: contact.open,
                    onShow: contact.show,
                    onClose: contact.close
                });
            });
        });
    },
    open: function (dialog) {
        // dynamically determine height
        var h = 280;
        if ($('#contact-subject').length) {
            h += 26;
        }
        if ($('#contact-cc').length) {
            h += 22;
        }

        var title = $('#contact-container .contact-title').html();
        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Loading...');
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn(200, function () {
            dialog.container.fadeIn(200, function () {
                dialog.data.fadeIn(200, function () {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                        height: h
                    }, function () {
                        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html(title);
                        $('#contact-container form').fadeIn(200, function () {
                            $('#contact-container #contact-name').focus();

                            $('#contact-container .contact-cc').click(function () {
                                var cc = $('#contact-container #contact-cc');
                                cc.is(':checked') ? cc.attr('checked', '') : cc.attr('checked', 'checked');
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
    show: function (dialog) {
        $('#contact-container .contact-send').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // validate form
            if (contact.validate()) {
                var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message');
                msg.fadeOut(function () {
                    msg.removeClass('contact-error').empty();
                });
                $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Sending...');
                $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);
                $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                    height: '80px'
                }, function () {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeIn(200, function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/contact/data/contact.php',
                            data: $('#contact-container form').serialize() + '&action=send',
                            type: 'post',
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeOut(200, function () {
                                    $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Thank you!');
                                    msg.html(data).fadeIn(200);
                                });
                            },
                            error: contact.error
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                if ($('#contact-container .contact-message:visible').length > 0) {
                    var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message div');
                    msg.fadeOut(200, function () {
                        msg.empty();
                        contact.showError();
                        msg.fadeIn(200);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-message').animate({
                        height: '30px'
                    }, contact.showError);
                }

            }
        });
    },
    close: function (dialog) {
        $('#contact-container .contact-message').fadeOut();
        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Goodbye...');
        $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);
        $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
            height: 40
        }, function () {
            dialog.data.fadeOut(200, function () {
                dialog.container.fadeOut(200, function () {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $.modal.close();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    },
    validate: function () {
        contact.message = '';
        if (!$('#contact-container #contact-name').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Name is required. ';
        }

        var email = $('#contact-container #contact-email').val();
        if (!email) {
            contact.message += 'Email is required. ';
        }
        else {
            if (!contact.validateEmail(email)) {
                contact.message += 'Email is invalid. ';
            }
        }

        if (!$('#contact-container #contact-message').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Message is required.';
        }

        if (contact.message.length > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    validateEmail: function (email) {
        var at = email.lastIndexOf("@");

        // Make sure the at (@) sybmol exists and  
        // it is not the first or last character
        if (at < 1 || (at + 1) === email.length)
            return false;

        // Make sure there aren't multiple periods together
        if (/(\.{2,})/.test(email))
            return false;

        // Break up the local and domain portions
        var local = email.substring(0, at);
        var domain = email.substring(at + 1);

        // Check lengths
        if (local.length < 1 || local.length > 64 || domain.length < 4 || domain.length > 255)
            return false;

        // Make sure local and domain don't start with or end with a period
        if (/(^\.|\.$)/.test(local) || /(^\.|\.$)/.test(domain))
            return false;

        // Check for quoted-string addresses
        // Since almost anything is allowed in a quoted-string address,
        // we're just going to let them go through
        if (!/^"(.+)"$/.test(local)) {
            // It's a dot-string address...check for valid characters
            if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%*\/?|^{}`~&'+=_\.]*$/.test(local))
                return false;
        }

        // Make sure domain contains only valid characters and at least one period
        if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/.test(domain) || domain.indexOf(".") === -1)
            return false;   

        return true;
    },
    showError: function () {
        $('#contact-container .contact-message')
            .html($('<div class="contact-error"></div>').append(contact.message))
            .fadeIn(200);
    }
};

contact.init();

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the functionality you are looking for? 
See: 
http://www.joecodeman.com/ITServices/Demos/jQuery/ShowDemo_v01a.html

If this is the effect dgbenner is looking for... then it is just a matter of organizing his/her code so it works correctly.

The basic effect dgbenner is trying to achieve is very simple. Therefore, the code just needs to be organized correctly.

This is the basic code / pseudo code:

```
//1) run the currently selected effect
function runEffect() {

//2) Hide the button`
  $( "#eMailButton" ).fadeOut();  


  //3) Show the email form
  $( "#effect" ).show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );

  //4) Hide the email form and show the button again ( 4 seconds later in this demo...)
  // other effects and actions can be coded when the user submits his/her info..)
  function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $( "#effect:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();
      $( "#eMailButton" ).fadeIn();
    }, 4000 );
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. This is the right effect. However I'm trying to use a demo form because I know nothing about php. I was hoping my html code was correct and would pull in the php/js, which is far beyond my skill level. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Well... to get this done you will need to know more about PHP and JS and how the underlying architecture works.   PHP runs on the server and JS runs on the client. ( naturally, this can change depending on your platform ) 

Anyhow, you need to find a developer that can help you write the code.  

1st - You will need a client email form ( HTML, CSS and JS ). 
2nd - Your form will then send your customer data to the PHP page running on the server.  The PHP page then saves in info to the database.

Comment: By the way... your website landing page is very cool looking! :)